# jasperreports 5.5.0 with websphere 6.1

Tags: java, jasper-reports, websphere-6.1

Is it possible to run jasperreports 5.5.0 on a websphere 6.1 (java 1.5)

I have some jr5.5 reports (using multiple Bands in the DetailSetion and need it to run on a websphere 6.1

If I try to run it now I get a java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Comment: `Is it possible to run jasperreports 5.5.0` - What does it mean?

Comment: It means, that I want to use japerreports 5.5.0 with a websphere 6.1 server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not, because jasperreports 5.5.0 uses awt font kerning, so at least java 1.6 is required...